# How can I add a link to a photo in a list? I accidentally did it once but haven't been able to do it again

Tags: html, list, image, hyperlink

```
 <ul> 
    <li> <b>Goku</b>  </a> <br></a><img src="goku.jfif"></li>
```

I want to add a link for the Goku image so that if i click the photo, it takes me to another page.

Comment: Include an `img` tag inside an `a` tag to create a clickable image link. [W3 has a demo](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_links_image).

Comment: Your HTML is invalid

Answer (score 0):

You can put an `img` tag inside an `a` tag.

Like this:

```html
<a href="TARGET_URL_HERE">
    <img src="IMAGE_SOURCE_HERE"/>
</a>
```

You can try it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_links_image).